# jQuery hover div underneath another layer

Tags: jquery, hover

Is it possible to ignore all divs that are "above" the element that has hover binded to them with jQuery?  For example, I have an element A that has a hover event binded to it, but there also other elements B, C, D that are "absolute positioned" above element A.  So when the user's mouse moves over to element B, C, D, the hover event is no longer fired even if B, C, and D are directly above the element.  Is it possible to ignore elements B C and D?

**UPDATE:**
I'm actually trying to create a map (element A) with elements B, C, D as area labels.  So for example, for a map of New York state, you will have text elements "Manhattan", "New Jersey", etc overlapping the map.  This is why I need the hover to fire even if the user has his mouse over the labels.

Comment: Is this demonstrating your problem? http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/BqZ3R/

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 31):

If you can use CSS3 then you can set `pointer-events:none` for the absolutely positioned elements, see [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/rNWpz/).

[All modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events) support this property - only IE9 and below and Opera Mini do not support it (at the time of writing). It also means you will not have any pointer-events for those elements which might not be exactly what you want.

Comment: I _really_ like this approach, it's really useful when you have let's say big buttons with small text and you want the hover and click events to be fired when clicking in any part of the button. If you hover the text the result is like if there wasn't any text at all, just great!

Answer (score 4):

The way I see it, you have a few options:

- Do as Ivarska recommended, and create an empty element over all of them and use that for the trigger.
- Bind to the mousemove on the entire page and find when it's "inside the box" (i.e. over the target element)--basically, re-invent the hover event. (But not this adds some pretty serious overhead to your page)
- Redesign

You may be also able to bind to just the target (i.e. A) and any elements you have that may overlap A, then just check if the mouse position within the other control would hypothetically also be inside the A control. Less overhead than binding to the page and checking, but still more than typical.

Comment: @Brad Christie - There isn't any way to use event bubbling in this situation? Or am I misunderstanding event bubbling? http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html

Comment: @JaredFarrish: Top-most always takes priority: http://jsfiddle.net/taJtM/ (in hover anyways)

Comment: @Brad - So you mean it only fires the top-most event, and doesn't push down to the sub-element events?

Comment: @JaredFarrish: You [can](http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/cssHighlightTableRow/index2.html), you just have to tell it that every time element B fired a hover, it _should_ actually be saying element A is being hovered. (but this is only practical if B is a full overlap of A)

Comment: @Brad - Yeah, I was thinking that. If there is overlap, then the perimeter check is probably the way to go (still attaching hover to all elements within the perimeter). I don't like the overlay approach at all. Too artificial.

Comment: @JaredFarrish: This is what I mean by redirect: http://jsfiddle.net/taJtM/1/ -- just have them all trigger the same handle and work with it, checking `e.target` on the way. (Also, here's a partial overlap and the issue I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/taJtM/2/)

Comment: @Brad - Ok, so the example I posted is a version of a redirect? In my thought, as far as it's two-dimensional space, forget about the specific element and just fire the event on all elements, unless it specifically wouldn't work (as in the overlap scenario). The underlying element with the event is the one with the x,y real estate, so hovering over any element within that space would just participate in the scheme. The only thing I wonder about in this case is if the hover-out on the top-most elements could cause mischief if they fire the event handler artificially (race condition?).

Comment: @JaredFarrish: You're starting to get it. ;-) Here's an example with mouse clicks: http://jsfiddle.net/taJtM/4/ Considering the click is bound to all elements and you're clicking over all divs you'd expect it to travel "down" to all elements beneath the click--but it doesn't.

Comment: @Brad - Why doesn't it? I saw on the Quirksmode article that this was intentional (although Netscape and MS disagreed on implementation). Is this just to simplify implementation?

Comment: @JaredFarrish: I'd by lying if I said I knew, I can only report the facts. I am just aware it doesn't go through and fire the target event on all objects under that specific point. It may just be just just eliminate memory use, but that's only speculative.

Comment: @Brad - Do you know of any applications in which the behavior we're talking about is the way it works? Maybe it's just the way it should be, with a limited scope.

Comment: The problem is actually a lot harder than it seems.  Since I'm using poly area tags, the shapes in element A are not rectangular. They're very complex shapes, so elements B, C, and D may actually be overlapping more than one element, so recreating invisible elements is not practical (in fact it may not even work in my case). Binding the entire page is also not very practical. I seriously wonder how Google maps does this when they have so many different elements in their maps.

Comment: @PeterBZ: My guess is they use the whole area as a canvas, and use mouse location based on shapes they have in memory/know about.

Answer (score 4):

Use e.relatedTarget to determine if the user hovered over one of you nested (absolute) elements.  Maybe easier if you give your map labels a class

e.g:  To show you labels during a hover state on the map, and only hide them when the user leaves the map

```
    $("#map").hover(
      function(e) { 
        $(this).find(".labels").fadeIn();
      },

      function(e) {
        if( $(e.relatedTarget).hasClass("maplabel") ) {
          //The user has hovered over a label...Do nothing (or some other function)
        } else {
          // User has left the map and isn't over a label
          $(this).find(".labels").fadeOut();
      }
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I've got in mind right now is to create an invisible element at the top and give it the hover trigger.

Answer (score 0):

You could make the z-index of the A element higher then that of the B, C and D elements.

Answer (score 0):

Although there are different ways to fix this, probably the simplest would be to add the hover event to all of the elements:

**HTML**

```
<div id="a" class="hover"></div>
<div id="b" class="hover"></div>
<div id="c" class="hover"></div>
<div id="d" class="hover"></div>
<div id="state">unhovered</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#a {
    width: 350px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background-color: #ccc;
}
#b {
    position: absolute;
    top: 35px;
    left: 35px;
    width: 35px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background-color: #cca;
}
#c {
    position: absolute;
    top: 85px;
    left: 85px;
    width: 35px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background-color: #cca;
}
#d {
    position: absolute;
    top: 85px;
    left: 135px;
    width: 35px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background-color: #cca;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.hover').hover(
        function(){
            $('#state').text('hovered');
        },
        function(){
            $('#state').text('unhovered');
        }
    );
});
```

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/H5TAG/

Answer (score 0):

The z-index adjustment someone else mentioned works.  Make the z-index higher for the item you want to be recognized by hover.