# div display (with fading) on image hover

Tags: jquery, image, html, hover, fadein

On any of the peoples profiles you view at http://www.stacklaw.com.au/web/page/Our_People_Lawyer_Finder, I'd like to add some functionality to the "light box" frames that appear so that the quote for each person `<div class="qucon">` fades in when the mouse hovers over the person's image and fades out when mouse moves away from the image.

It'd be a bonus if I could have the div fade-in, display for 1 second, the fade-out on page (light box) load to sort of inform the viewer that the image has content...   But not essential.

Thanks

The developers of the site are using a js called "facebox" and the main file for it consists of:

```
/*
 * Facebox (for jQuery)
 * version: 1.3
 * @requires jQuery v1.2 or later
 * @homepage https://github.com/defunkt/facebox
 *
 * Licensed under the MIT:
 *   http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 *
 * Copyright Forever Chris Wanstrath, Kyle Neath
 *
 * Usage:
 *
 *  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
 *    jQuery('a[rel*=facebox]').facebox()
 *  })
 *
 *  <a href="#terms" rel="facebox">Terms</a>
 *    Loads the #terms div in the box
 *
 *  <a href="terms.html" rel="facebox">Terms</a>
 *    Loads the terms.html page in the box
 *
 *  <a href="terms.png" rel="facebox">Terms</a>
 *    Loads the terms.png image in the box
 *
 *
 *  You can also use it programmatically:
 *
 *    jQuery.facebox('some html')
 *    jQuery.facebox('some html', 'my-groovy-style')
 *
 *  The above will open a facebox with "some html" as the content.
 *
 *    jQuery.facebox(function($) {
 *      $.get('blah.html', function(data) { $.facebox(data) })
 *    })
 *
 *  The above will show a loading screen before the passed function is called,
 *  allowing for a better ajaxy experience.
 *
 *  The facebox function can also display an ajax page, an image, or the contents of a div:
 *
 *    jQuery.facebox({ ajax: 'remote.html' })
 *    jQuery.facebox({ ajax: 'remote.html' }, 'my-groovy-style')
 *    jQuery.facebox({ image: 'stairs.jpg' })
 *    jQuery.facebox({ image: 'stairs.jpg' }, 'my-groovy-style')
 *    jQuery.facebox({ div: '#box' })
 *    jQuery.facebox({ div: '#box' }, 'my-groovy-style')
 *
 *  Want to close the facebox?  Trigger the 'close.facebox' document event:
 *
 *    jQuery(document).trigger('close.facebox')
 *
 *  Facebox also has a bunch of other hooks:
 *
 *    loading.facebox
 *    beforeReveal.facebox
 *    reveal.facebox (aliased as 'afterReveal.facebox')
 *    init.facebox
 *    afterClose.facebox
 *
 *  Simply bind a function to any of these hooks:
 *
 *   $(document).bind('reveal.facebox', function() { ...stuff to do after the facebox and contents are revealed... })
 *
 */
(function($) {
  $.facebox = function(data, klass) {
    $.facebox.loading(data.settings || [])

    if (data.ajax) fillFaceboxFromAjax(data.ajax, klass)
    else if (data.image) fillFaceboxFromImage(data.image, klass)
    else if (data.div) fillFaceboxFromHref(data.div, klass)
    else if ($.isFunction(data)) data.call($)
    else $.facebox.reveal(data, klass)
  }

  /*
   * Public, $.facebox methods
   */

  $.extend($.facebox, {
    settings: {
      opacity      : 0.2,
      overlay      : true,
      loadingImage : '/templates/faqint/2011/images/loading.gif',
      closeImage   : '/templates/stacks/css/closelabel.gif',
      imageTypes   : [ 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif' ],
      faceboxHtml  : '\
    <div id="facebox" style="display:none;"> \
      <div class="popup"> \
        <div class="content"> \
        </div> \
        <a href="#" class="close"></a> \
      </div> \
    </div>'
    },

    loading: function() {
      init()
      if ($('#facebox .loading').length == 1) return true
      showOverlay()

      $('#facebox .content').empty().
        append('<div class="loading"><img src="'+$.facebox.settings.loadingImage+'"/></div>')

      $('#facebox').show().css({
        top:    getPageScroll()[1] + (getPageHeight() / 10),
        left:   $(window).width() / 2 - ($('#facebox .popup').outerWidth() / 2)
      })

      $(document).bind('keydown.facebox', function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 27) $.facebox.close()
        return true
      })
      $(document).trigger('loading.facebox')
    },

    reveal: function(data, klass) {
      $(document).trigger('beforeReveal.facebox')
      if (klass) $('#facebox .content').addClass(klass)
      $('#facebox .content').empty().append(data)
      $('#facebox .popup').children().fadeIn('normal')
      $('#facebox').css('left', $(window).width() / 2 - ($('#facebox .popup').outerWidth() / 2))
      $(document).trigger('reveal.facebox').trigger('afterReveal.facebox')
    },

    close: function() {
      $(document).trigger('close.facebox')
      return false
    }
  })

  /*
   * Public, $.fn methods
   */

  $.fn.facebox = function(settings) {
    if ($(this).length == 0) return

    init(settings)

    function clickHandler() {
      $.facebox.loading(true)

      // support for rel="facebox.inline_popup" syntax, to add a class
      // also supports deprecated "facebox[.inline_popup]" syntax
      var klass = this.rel.match(/facebox\[?\.(\w+)\]?/)
      if (klass) klass = klass[1]

      fillFaceboxFromHref(this.href, klass)
      return false
    }

    return this.bind('click.facebox', clickHandler)
  }

  /*
   * Private methods
   */

  // called one time to setup facebox on this page
  function init(settings) {
    if ($.facebox.settings.inited) return true
    else $.facebox.settings.inited = true

    $(document).trigger('init.facebox')
    makeCompatible()

    var imageTypes = $.facebox.settings.imageTypes.join('|')
    $.facebox.settings.imageTypesRegexp = new RegExp('\\.(' + imageTypes + ')(\\?.*)?$', 'i')

    if (settings) $.extend($.facebox.settings, settings)
    $('body').append($.facebox.settings.faceboxHtml)

    var preload = [ new Image(), new Image() ]
    preload[0].src = $.facebox.settings.closeImage
    preload[1].src = $.facebox.settings.loadingImage

    $('#facebox').find('.b:first, .bl').each(function() {
      preload.push(new Image())
      preload.slice(-1).src = $(this).css('background-image').replace(/url\((.+)\)/, '$1')
    })

    $('#facebox .close')
      .click($.facebox.close)
      .append('<img src="'
              + $.facebox.settings.closeImage
              + '" class="close_image" title="close">')
  }

  // getPageScroll() by quirksmode.com
  function getPageScroll() {
    var xScroll, yScroll;
    if (self.pageYOffset) {
      yScroll = self.pageYOffset;
      xScroll = self.pageXOffset;
    } else if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop) {     // Explorer 6 Strict
      yScroll = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
      xScroll = document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
    } else if (document.body) {// all other Explorers
      yScroll = document.body.scrollTop;
      xScroll = document.body.scrollLeft;
    }
    return new Array(xScroll,yScroll)
  }

  // Adapted from getPageSize() by quirksmode.com
  function getPageHeight() {
    var windowHeight
    if (self.innerHeight) { // all except Explorer
      windowHeight = self.innerHeight;
    } else if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.clientHeight) { // Explorer 6 Strict Mode
      windowHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    } else if (document.body) { // other Explorers
      windowHeight = document.body.clientHeight;
    }
    return windowHeight
  }

  // Backwards compatibility
  function makeCompatible() {
    var $s = $.facebox.settings

    $s.loadingImage = $s.loading_image || $s.loadingImage
    $s.closeImage = $s.close_image || $s.closeImage
    $s.imageTypes = $s.image_types || $s.imageTypes
    $s.faceboxHtml = $s.facebox_html || $s.faceboxHtml
  }

  // Figures out what you want to display and displays it
  // formats are:
  //     div: #id
  //   image: blah.extension
  //    ajax: anything else
  function fillFaceboxFromHref(href, klass) {
    // div
    if (href.match(/#/)) {
      var url    = window.location.href.split('#')[0]
      var target = href.replace(url,'')
      if (target == '#') return
      $.facebox.reveal($(target).html(), klass)

    // image
    } else if (href.match($.facebox.settings.imageTypesRegexp)) {
      fillFaceboxFromImage(href, klass)
    // ajax
    } else {
      fillFaceboxFromAjax(href, klass)
    }
  }

  function fillFaceboxFromImage(href, klass) {
    var image = new Image()
    image.onload = function() {
      $.facebox.reveal('<div class="image"><img src="' + image.src + '" /></div>', klass)
    }
    image.src = href
  }

  function fillFaceboxFromAjax(href, klass) {
    $.facebox.jqxhr = $.get(href, function(data) { $.facebox.reveal(data, klass) })
  }

  function skipOverlay() {
    return $.facebox.settings.overlay == false || $.facebox.settings.opacity === null
  }

  function showOverlay() {
    if (skipOverlay()) return

    if ($('#facebox_overlay').length == 0)
      $("body").append('<div id="facebox_overlay" class="facebox_hide"></div>')

    $('#facebox_overlay').hide().addClass("facebox_overlayBG")
      .css('opacity', $.facebox.settings.opacity)
      .click(function() { $(document).trigger('close.facebox') })
      .fadeIn(200)
    return false
  }

  function hideOverlay() {
    if (skipOverlay()) return

    $('#facebox_overlay').fadeOut(200, function(){
      $("#facebox_overlay").removeClass("facebox_overlayBG")
      $("#facebox_overlay").addClass("facebox_hide")
      $("#facebox_overlay").remove()
    })

    return false
  }

  /*
   * Bindings
   */

  $(document).bind('close.facebox', function() {
    if ($.facebox.jqxhr) {
      $.facebox.jqxhr.abort()
      $.facebox.jqxhr = null
    }
    $(document).unbind('keydown.facebox')
    $('#facebox').fadeOut(function() {
      $('#facebox .content').removeClass().addClass('content')
      $('#facebox .loading').remove()
      $(document).trigger('afterClose.facebox')
    })
    hideOverlay()
  })

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: well, your requirements almost meet up with jQuery`s tooltip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the profile page put this code in there somewhere:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".qucon").hide();
        $("#ProfileMainBody img, .qucon").hover(
               function(){
            $(".qucon").fadeIn('fast');
              },
              function(){
            $(".qucon").fadeOut('fast');
              }
        ); 
    });
   </script>
```

Comment: I tried this and it seems to have no effect.
Can to change your . (after 'iframe') to a , though

Comment: Your fancyBox code needs to be updated, I see the error you're having now, you need to replace the right code with this one. You can't put this function in the middle of nowhere.

Comment: or you can take out `function(){` `}` out from around the code how you have it now.

Comment: I must be missing something, or our site has some conflict/nuance that isn't being noticed.  I updated the code with your edit and it still has no effect.

Comment: nice!.   the only issue with that is that it flashes when the mouse is moved across the "shown" div.

Comment: Update that same line, it was wrong before.

Comment: I picked that up too and can see what you've done.  It's reduced the flashing, but hasn't eliminated it...

Comment: See this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5213159/jquery-hover-div-underneath-another-layer

Comment: I'm still working through that to see if any of their suggestions suit my case, but would the "flash" issue be eliminated if I didn't use the FadIn/fadeOut?

Comment: switched to using show() and hide() and the flashing is not there anymore.  I will use this for now unless there is a way to correct the perceived flash (which is really just a delay due to the fade).

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code

```
$('.test').hide();
$('.qucon').hover(function () {                     
         $('.test').fadeIn();         

  }, function () {
      $('.test').fadeOut();          
  });
```

Refer Demo [See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dubeynee/cn9Fk/3/)

Hope it helps you

Comment: Hi @neeraj. Out of curiosity from the fiddle that you have provided, would like to know that when you rapidly move your mouse over and do a mouse out of the image, the text 'this is test' blinks for some seconds depending on how fast and till how much time you do mouse over and mouse out. That looks funny. Can this be restricted and the text should stop blinking on such events?

Comment: Thanks for catching please update code  if (!$('.test').is(":animated")) i have also update demo please refer [link](http://jsfiddle.net/dubeynee/cn9Fk/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the CSS Solution.

Situation on load.

```
.qucon{
opacity:0;
}
```

Situation on hover with the transition.

```
.qucon:hover{
opacity:1;
transition: background-color 0.2s ease 0s, border 0.2s ease 0s, color 0.2s ease 0s, opacity 0.2s ease-in-out 0s, outline 0.2s ease 0s;
}
```

Hope this helps.